# Signing petitions and data entry

Tags: civicampaign, civipetiton

I have a survey which I am asking people to sign on line. The fields are activities and it is a campaign petition.

I also have a bunch of surveys filled in offline on paper.

I can upload the activities - which I have done but these people don't show up as having signed the petition. I have to do two separate searches - one for the activities and one for the petition.

Has anybody got any idea how I can have this data in one place. I can't just sign the petition for multiple people because civicrm is too clever for that (or so it seems to me!)

Ideas very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this using webform in drupal